# MySQL row position

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to get the row position from a grouped query.

```
SELECT x.id, x.position, x.name, x.total FROM (
    SELECT u.*, count(invites.user_id) as total, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position 
    FROM users u JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r 
    LEFT JOIN invites i ON i.user_id = u.id AND i.status = 2 
    GROUP BY u.id 
    ORDER BY total DESC
) x
WHERE x.id = 2004
```

But my rank is getting out wrong. The rownum is not counting correctly the position of the row. Maybe something about the join and group?

Example of multiple selects, with some ids, on a table:

```
    id  total   position
    10  15  250
    158 13  124
    3   10  4
    (...)
```

The error here is that id = 3 shoud be on the 3rd position and not on the 4th. And the id = 10 should be 1st, and not on 250th position, and so on..

A better example:

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6461e/2)

Comment: How is it wrong?  What is the problem?

Comment: @GordonLinoff i've updated my question with a sample output

Comment: . . How are you getting multiple rows of output if you are grouping by `id` and then selecting only one `id`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry, i explained myself wrong. that is not the output of a single select, its the output of multiple runs with id = ..

Comment: . . Could you have a column called `total` in one of the tables?

Comment: @GordonLinoff total is the count of "count(invites.user_id) as total" .. so that i know how many invites were done by that particular user

Comment: @GordonLinoff sqlfiddler example in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.  The problem in the sample Fiddle is that the sort is not stable.  There are multiple values where the total is 1, and these can be ordered in an arbitrary way.  And, they clearly are.

You can introduce a stable sort by including an additional column in the sort to uniquely identify each row.  For the SQL Fiddle example, the queries would be:

```
SELECT `rank`
FROM (select @rownum:=@rownum+1 `rank`, p.names, count(p.names) as total 
      from TableName p, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r 
      group by names
      order by total, p.names DESC
    ) s
WHERE names = 'ship';

SELECT p.names, count(p.names) as total 
FROM TableName P
GROUP BY names
ORDER BY total desc, p.names;
```

EDIT:

I see the problem.  Using an additional layer of subqueries seems to fix the problem:

```
select n.*
from (SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 as `rank`, n.*
      FROM (select p.names, count(p.names) as total 
            from TableName p cross join (SELECT @rownum:=0) r 
            group by names
           ) n
      order by total desc, names
     ) n
where names = 'mango';
```

(SQL Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6461e/24).)

This is very curious behavior and don't understand it.  I wonder if it is related to the implicit ordering after a `group by`.

Comment: If you run it, it will return rank = 8, but in fact, if you count row by row on the lower table, it will be on the 9th position. Also if you change the names = 'ship' to 'mango', it will return rank = 2, and thats not true..

Comment: That in fact worked.. why, i really dont know. Maybe someone else can complement the answer with some sort of explanation.. Thank you.